# How do I get VMware Workstation 8.0.4 working on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit?

Tags: 64-bit, virtualization, vmware

I've bought VMware Workstation 8 just today. After the installation I launched it and the application noticed me that "several modules must be compiled and loaded into the running kernel".

During the process, VMware noticed me that was impossible to configure Virtual Network Devices and at the end, was impossible to start the services.

The last message said that further information could be found at this address:  `/tmp/vmware-root-975001794/modconfig-22789.log`

So, I've pasted the [content of the log message here](http://pastie.org/4170487).

Can you help me or, rather, you suggest to wait for future updates of Ubuntu?
My desktop environment is Unity.

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer to your question (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 3):

#### A simple patch needs to be applied to the module sources

The patch is described and available on [this page](http://weltall.heliohost.org/wordpress/2012/01/26/vmware-workstation-8-0-2-player-4-0-2-fix-for-linux-kernel-3-2-and-3-3/), but the version in there needs to be changed to 8.0.4 to apply successfully.

**Here's how:**

To *download and* apply the patch,

- Open a terminal and type:

  ```
  mkdir vmw_patch && cd vmw_patch
  wget -O- http://weltall.heliohost.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/vmware802fixlinux320.tar.gz | tar -xz
  sed -i -e 's/8.0.2/8.0.4/g' patch-modules_3.2.0.sh 
  ./patch-modules_3.2.0.sh
  ```
- That should compile the modules without any errors.

> *Explanation:* `wget` downloads the patch, and `tar` extracts it without actually saving the downloaded file. `sed` updates 8.0.2 to 8.0.4 in the patching script so that it will run.

Answer (score 0):

[izx](https://askubuntu.com/users/58612/izx)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/157555/22949) worked for me with two exceptions:

1. I had to run the script as root.
2. Since I had already applied the same patch earlier when I upgraded from 8.02 to 8.03, I had to remove the old patch flag file and re-run the patch:

   ```
   sudo rm /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/.patched
   sudo ./patch-modules_3.2.0.sh
   ```

You can find a detailed guide including the above at [this blog post](http://hashprompt.blogspot.in/2012/10/vmware-workstation-804-installation-on.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thank [you](https://askubuntu.com/a/157555/22949) [both](https://askubuntu.com/a/158752/22949) very much for the solution. The only thing I noticed was that I needed to install "patch" with:

```
sudo apt-get install patch
```

I'm not sure if this is present on the default install, but I didn't have it for whatever reason. Either way, thank you both so much!

Answer (score 0):

When following [izx](https://askubuntu.com/users/58612/izx)'s [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/157555/22949), if you have **VMware Player** rather than VMware Workstation, you'll use this command (instead of the `sed ...` command given there):

```
sed -i -e 's/4.0.2/4.0.4/g' patch-modules_3.2.0.sh
```