# How to install VMware Workstation in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, vmware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get VMware Workstation 8.0.4 working on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157529/how-do-i-get-vmware-workstation-8-0-4-working-on-ubuntu-12-04-64-bit)

I am totally new to a Unix/Linux based OS. Ubuntu 12.04 is my first Linux experience and I can not install `VMware Workstation`. I wish to know how to do install it in a step by step way.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 in a Toshiba Satellite A205-S5831; I have 2 GB of RAM and the detailed specification of my laptop is [here](http://www.cnet.com/laptops/toshiba-satellite-a205-s5831/4507-3121_7-32906215.html).

Comment: Do you have VMWare handy?  What version?

Comment: ^This and you also have low memory for virtualization purposes. Are you sure you want to proceed with Workstation installation before upgrading your RAM size?

Answer (score 0):

Very clearly written... you can find a detailed guide at http://hashprompt.blogspot.in/2012/10/vmware-workstation-804-installation-on.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Even though it's pretty clear you're not trying to conceal this information, we still require that you [explicitly disclose](http://askubuntu.com/faq#promotion) that you're linking to your own blog, when doing so. At minimum, please edit your post to include such disclosure. In addition, [it would be even better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Furthermore, this question is about VMware Player and your blog post is about VMware Workstation, so you may want to add explanation.